# JQuery/JS как изменить value у input взяв данные с ассоциативного массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, onchange, each

У меня есть объект:

```
{"name":"Name", "age": 20}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" value=""/>
<input class="form-control" name="age" value=""/>
```

Как с помощью JQuery или JS можно заменить все input value, взяв данные с объекта?

Answer (score 3):

```js
function assignValues() {
  var data = {"name":"Name", "age": 20};
  for (var key in data) {
    var inp = document.querySelector("[name='" + key + "']");
    if (inp)
      inp.value = data[key];
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" name="name" value=""/>
<input class="form-control" name="age" value=""/>
<br/>
<button onclick="assignValues()">Click</button>
```